# How to get Bluetooth Pairing Request Alert result？

Tags: bluetooth, request, pairing

I'm developing a BLE App. When I connect to a peripheral, the system will pop a “Bluetooth Pairing Request” alert. now，I want to know how to get the Cancel button or the pairing button for the user tapped，Because it is important to me，Thank you.

[image: enter image description]

Comment: Hi，can you found solution?